# XMLin with strings containing invalid xml characters

Tags: perl, xml-simple

I am using XML::Simple in one of my perl scripts to extract some messages, problem is I am getting this error :

```
No semi-colon found after entity name [Ln: 1, Col: 151]
```

when I use `XMLin( $msg )` and `$msg` contains an invalid character like '&'

I know I can use regex to remove them, but I don't want to. I can use replace & with `&amp;`.

Is there a simple way in perl to deal with this kind of invalid characters in strings when I use `XMLin( $msg )` ?

Example for `$msg` can be like : `<Error>Exception Invalid address (&F5F5F5F5)</Error>`

Comment: If you post an example `$msg`, we can probably give you an answer on parsing it. `XML::Simple` is not the answer. Trying to hand off broken XML to a parser is also not a good plan.

Comment: @Sobrique, I added an example message

Comment: Well, that's never going to work - it's not XML in the first place, so how do you expect to parse it as XML?

Comment: @Sobrique actually that.

Answer (score 2):

No.

XML::Simple doesn't actually parse XML. It uses one of many other parsers to do so. If it had such an option, it wouldn't always work, if ever.

XML::Simple, therefore, doesn't provide such an option.

Comment: Thanks. I think what is the root cause in my case is : I am getting this string from a java program where it parses another xml. There it was calling node.getTextContent()  and that call is not preserving the character `&amp;` it is converting it into `&` and giving me the string. Later when I feed it to XMLin it fails. How to get the text as it is from the node ? Do you have any idea?

Comment: @svasa you should ask a new question in the _java_ tag and ask there, but make sure to be specific.

Comment: That's not the root cause. `getTextContent` is behaving correctly. It resolves entities because the caller shouldn't have to care about how it the text was encoded. Why are you passing the text of an XML node to `XMLin`? Do you (weirdly) have XML embedded in your XML? If so, the original should look like `<ele>&lt;Error&gt;...(&amp;amp;F5F5F5F5)&amp;&lt;/Error&gt;</ele>` instead of `<ele>&lt;Error&gt;...(&amp;F5F5F5F5)&amp;&lt;/Error&gt;</ele>`.